# Is there a way to declare a Property/DependencyProperty to use TwoWay binding by default if its bound?

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, user-controls

Controls like the `TextBox` use `TwoWay` Binding by default

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text1}" />
```

However with Custom User Controls, I will need something like

```
<local:UserControl1 Text="{Binding Text1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Is there a way I can set bindings on a property to use TwoWay Bindings by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare property, use [`FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions(VS.90).aspx).

```
public DependencyProperty SomeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Some", typeof(bool), typeof(Window1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(bool),
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```