# How to use TwoWay binding from within a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, controltemplate

I have my own UserControl, a `LabeledTextBox` which is the combination of a `Label` and a..well, `TextBox`. This Control has two properties: `Caption` which will be bound to the caption of the `Label`, and `Value` which will be bound to the `Text` of the `TextBox`.

Code:

```
public class LabeledTextBox : Control
{
    static LabeledTextBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LabeledTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LabeledTextBox)));
    }

    public string Caption
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Caption.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));


    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));


}
```

XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:LabeledTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:LabeledTextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Caption}" />
                    <TextBox  Name="Box" Margin="3,0,3,3" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<uc:LabeledTextBox Caption="Code:" Value="{Binding ExpenseCode}"  />
```

Initially I thought I had found my answer here: [WPF TemplateBinding vs RelativeSource TemplatedParent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1131222/466903)

That details the difference between `TemplateBinding` and `RelativeSource TemplatedParent`. I've changed my code accordingly, but it still feels like I'm missing a step. The OneWay binding does work, my textbox is bound to the Value property, but changes do not register.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried making your Value dependency property TwoWay aswell? Or is the problem that the TextBox does not write into your Value dp?

Comment: Is it `LabeledTextBox.Value` that isn't changing or is it `ExpenseCode` in the data object? You could add a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) to the `Value` dependency property to see if it gets called.

Comment: @dowhilefor: is that not what the `Mode=TwoWay` in the XAML is for?
@Clemens: I initially did have that callback, and it did get called. In that callback I set the value of the textbox. Do I need to explicitly make the data go back from within the DP?
@Ricibob: thanks, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @diggingforfire Looks like everything is ok with the twoway binding inside your control. TwoWay was just missing at the `ExpenseCode` binding, as @akanksha has answered.

Comment: @diggingforfire Your TwoWay Mode is set from TextBox <-> UserControl ... but your user control exposes the value property, which uses a one way binding so your have Usedcontrol -> UserControl <-> TextBox. Remember that 2 bindings are active, the templatebinding and the "user" binding.

Comment: @dowhilefor: That explains exactly what I was wondering, great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the mode here.

```
<uc:LabeledTextBox Caption="Code:" Value="{Binding ExpenseCode,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

it worked at my end

Comment: I tried all possible combinations of mode at the style n the declaration. @dowhile is right, thanks for the explaination :)

Comment: I'm not quite a WPF adept yet, but that is a good approach :)

Answer (score 7):

Just in case anybody has this problem:

Another approach (maybe more elegant) would be to declare the dependency property of the usercontrol in a way so that it defaults to two way binding (e.g. as the framework TextBox does by default).

This can be achieved as follows (taken from the answer of [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237454/is-there-a-way-to-declare-a-property-dependencyproperty-to-use-twoway-binding-by)):

```
    public DependencyProperty SomeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Some", typeof(bool), typeof(Window1),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(bool),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

The key here is using `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`.